# Lenovo G700, New SSD Ubuntu clean 14.04LTS, Want to Use old Ubuntu Programs in orignial HHD installed in Optical Drive bay

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a Lenovo G700 that I had Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on, I put an SSD in and did a clean install of 14.04 I want to put the original HDD in the Optical drive bay and want to use the original programs that I had installed on it.

Is that possible or would it be better just to reinstall them to the system and wipe the HDD and make it just my Home dir?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By running applications from your original HDD (even if you'd be able to make it work), you'd bypass the package management (`apt`). Don't do that! You wouldn't receive any updates on your applications and they might be vulnerable to attacks from outside (for example, your webbrowser) or have unresolved, breaking bugs.

If you don't have *very* limited bandwith, just go with a clean, new install of all your applications. Simple as that. Thinking of it, even limited bandwith is no good excuse. Just don't do it.

Comment: Thank You Just needed to know a good reason and that one is the best reason to go clean.